# How to render the emojis in webbrowser in js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using get the emojis from the mobile app as unicodes 
`\ud83d\ude0d\ud83d\ude0d\ud83d\ude0d\ud83d\ude0d\ud83d\ude0d\ud83d\ude0d\ud83d\ude0d\ud83d\ude0d\ud83d\ude0d\ud83d\ude18\ud83d\ude18\ud83d\ude18`.

When I'm trying to render this in webbrowser it is not rendering. So I wrote another function

```
emojiString = function(s) {
       try{
        return eval("(function(){ return '" + s + "'})()");
       }catch(err){
           console.log("error in EmojiString"+err.stack);
           return s;
       }
    };
```

When I send the unicodes to this function everything was fine. But, when my string has `()` and for some special characters it is showing some error like unexpected token or "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid Unicode escape sequence".

How I can render the emojis in browser with unicodes?

Comment: "it is showing some error." - What error?

Comment: What was the first thing you tried before the attempt posted in the question?

Comment: It will throw an error like Unexpected token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your strings contain \u200b and \u200c - zero-width spaces

This fails because of the invisible zero-width spaces

```js
 var s = "\ud83d\ude0d\ud83d\ude0d\ud83d\ude0d\ud83d\ude0d\ud83d\ude0d‌​\ud83d\ude0d\ud83d\u‌​de0d\ud83d\ude0d\ud8‌​3d\ude0d\ud83d\ude18‌​\ud83d\ude18\ud83d\u‌​de18".replace(/[\u200b-\u200d]/,"")

console.log(s)
```

This will work:

```js
var s = document.getElementById("x").innerHTML;
console.log("before removing zero-width spaces",s.length);
s=s.replace(/[\u200b\u200c\u200d\ufeff]/g,"");
console.log("after removing zero-width spaces",s.length)
var em = JSON.parse('{"x":"'+s+'"}')
document.getElementById("y").innerHTML = em.x;
```

```html
The div below contain zero-width spaces:

<div id="x">\ud83d\ude0d\ud83d\ude0d\ud83d\ude0d\ud83d\ude0d\ud83d\ude0d‌​\ud83d\ude0d\ud83d\u‌​de0d\ud83d\ude0d\ud8‌​3d\ude0d\ud83d\ude18‌​\ud83d\ude18\ud83d\u‌​de18</div>
<div id="y"></div>
```

Comment: 1. some special characters are not rendering in chat like (" , ' )
2. while editing message ? is not showing in the inline textarea \ud83d\ude0d\ud83d\ude0d\ud83d\ude0d\ud83d\ude0d\ud83d\ude0d\ud83d\ude0d\ud83d\ude0d\ud83d\ude0d\ud83d\ude0d\ud83d\ude18\ud83d\ude18\ud83d\ude18

Comment: If you try with above one it won't render the emojis and it will throw error.